# How to make a voice sound heavier and more mature in Audacity?

Tags: audio, voice-manipulation

I am making a game, and I am using my voice for the sound effects of the spells of the cleric. I'm saying some things in latin.

What I want to do is modify my voice so that it sounds more mature and more "tenor".

I tried modifying the pitch values in Audacity, but no luck yet.

Can anyone point me in the direction to do this?

Comment: While recording speak through a tube, 4 ft length with 3 to 4 inch diameter should do nicely. Keep mic at other end of tube opening.

Comment: Can't believe this works. I can't believe I didn't think about this before. It is funny that I am so used to computing-based solutions that I didn't consider this. Seriously, thank you so much.

Comment: Cool! Glad this appeals to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly drop the pitch, but the tricky bit is that a tenor voice has a very different timbre - there are different harmonics, different resonances etc.

The preferred solution would be to get someone with a deep voice to help you :-)

If you have no-one else to help then try a combination of lowering the pitch, and stretching the time frame. The two together can help.

Alternatively, there are apps (for iPhone, Android, PC etc) which will change your voice - some are pretty silly, but some don't just change the pitch, but they change the tone, so that could be what you want.

Google for **Voice changer**